# How to route public folder requests in React when using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, image, directory, react-router-dom, public

My application deals with millions of images.  These images can not be imported due to their volume and variable directories.  I'm using react-router-dom, as this app is not a single page.  I can't figure out how to get react-router-dom to handle the public folder requests.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain in detail ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a separate image server with Node, works great.  Downside is images are public, yet placed in folders and with file names of UUIDs.